# How to send custom DHCP option on all Offer and Ack packets in kea?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, dhcp-option

I'm using the Kea dhcp server, and I want to use the DHCP options to send data to the server's clients. Following the instructions [here](https://kea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arm/dhcp4-srv.html#standard-dhcpv4-options), I listed the option with the `"always-send": true` field set.

However, this seems to only send it in the initial `Discover -> Offer -> Request -> Ack` process. When the client renews its lease, it does a shorter `Request -> Ack` sequence in which kea does not provide the custom option in question. I need to send it again because the value may have been changed since the client last connected.

How do I configure Kea such that it will send my DHCP options in all of the Acks to renew a lease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell (reinforced by the deafening silence from other people on this question), this isn't something Kea supports by default. I wrote a custom Kea hook to send the DHCP options that I want to send (documentation for how to do this is available on their website).